# How to show proof of funds for parents UK visitor visa

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

My parents are applying for visitor visa to the UK. My father receives a monthly pension. This comes into my mother's and father's joint account. My mother has Fixed Deposits (FD) under her name. Including the pension and FDs, they have sufficient funds for the trip.

Can they enter the total amount from FDs and pension in each application form, or can only my mother enter income from FDs in her form as they are only in her name.

Also, is a letter needed stating that father has the permission to use the money from FDs for the trip?